# Getting Foreach Data

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I am trying to get foreach data I am using jquery to submit the page without a refresh being required for some reason jQuery is not retrieving the foreach data, It needs to loop through each admin input field to see each data seperatly.

If it's not possible I won't use JQuery for this but thought I ask

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['admin_add']) AND is_array($_POST['admin_add'])) {
    foreach($_POST['admin_add'] as $admin_add) {
        if(strlen($admin_add) > 0) {
            // $sql=mysql_query("insert into hobbies(hobby)values('$hobby')");
        }
    }
}

die('<h3>'.$admin_add.'<h3/>');
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var clan_url_string = window.location.search.substring(1);
    // Make a function that returns the data, then call it whenever you
    // need the current values
    function getData() {
        return {
            clan_title_edit: $('#clan_title_edit').val(),
            clan_des: $('#clan_des').val(),
            admin_add: $('#admin_add').val(),
            //remember_me: ($('#remember_me').is(':checked')) ? 1 : 0
        }
    }

    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#background_cycler').fadeIn(1500);//fade the background back in once all the images are loaded
        setInterval('cycleImages()', 4000); // run every 4s
    });


    function loading(e) {
        $('#loading_status').show();
    }

    function hide_loading(e) {
        $('#loading_status').hide();
    }

    function success_message(e) {
        $('#success_login').html("We're Just Signing You In");
    }

    function clearfields() {
        $('#login-username').val('');  //Clear the user login id field
        $('#login_password').val('');  //Clear the user login password field        
    }

    function check(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/save_settings.php?'+clan_url_string,
            type: 'post',
            error: function () {
                //If your response from the server is a statuscode error. do this!!!'

                hide_loading(e);
                $('#status_message').html('<b>Something Has Gone Wrong</b><br> Please Try Again Later');
            },

            beforeSend: function () {
                loading(e);
            },

            data: {
                clan_title_edit: $('#clan_title_edit').val(), 
                clan_des: $('#clan_des').val(),
                admin_add: $('#admin_add').val(),
                remember_me: ($('#remember_me').is(':checked')) 
            }, // get current values

            success: function (data) {
                //if your response is a plain text. (e.g incorrect username or password)
                hide_loading(e);
                $('#status_message').hide();
                $('#status_message').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    // Don't repeat so much; use the same function for both handlers
    $('#login_content').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var username = $('#login-username').val();
            check(e);
        }
    });

    $('#submit_clan_settings').click(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 13) {
            check(e);
        }
    });
```

There's the php and jquery

Thanks

> Yes its SQL injection prone, havent fix this yet and I should be using `mysqli` or `$db->`);

Comment: Ummm, is your javascript even outputting to the browser? Your script dies before it reaches that code.

Comment: The PHP expects `$_POST['admin_add']` to be an array. But the AJAX call has `admin_add: $('#admin_add').val()`, which is just a single string.

Comment: What do you mean by _loop through each admin input field_? Do you have multiple input fields with `id="admin_add"`? IDs are supposed to be unique.